# Poor performance on high volume data sets

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am having poor performance on queries on classes that have a high record count. I am running some pretty straight forward queries but the performance is unusable. I really like orientdb and this is my 5th development project with odb as a backend. However, this particular project is forcing me to look for alternatives.

Please see below for detailed explanation.

We have a `Parent` class which does not grow much, the entire dataset has roughly 900 records.

However, the `Child` class, grows at a rate of 100k records over 15 minutes. It's generating millions of records on a daily basis.

**Records are inserted to the child class as an update/add of the parent.**

`create class Parent extends V
create class Child`

**Parent data model**

```
    {
        "id": string,
        "name": string,
        "rank": integer,
        "price_usd": float,
        "price_cny": float,
        "volume_24h_usd": float
        "market_cap_usd": float,
        "available_supply": integer,
        "total_supply": integer,
        "last_updated": datetime,
        "MarketName": string,
        "Exchange": string,
        "last_refresh": datetime
    }
```

**Child data model**

```
{
        "MarketName": string,
        "High": float,
        "Low": float,
        "Volume": float,
        "Last": float,
        "Bid": float,
        "Ask": float,
        "BaseVolume": float,
        "TimeStamp": datetime
    }
```

---

**Parent Data Sample**

```
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#506:403225",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "Parent",
        "MarketName": "USD-CNY",
        "High": 0.00026815,
        "Low": 0.00023002,
        "Volume": 17005.93615271,
        "Last": 0.00026103,
        "Bid": 0.00026104,
        "Ask": 0.000265,
        "BaseVolume": 4.15293493,
        "TimeStamp": "2017-07-15T18:28:11.857",
        "@fieldTypes": "High=d,Low=d,Volume=d,Last=d,Bid=d,Ask=d,BaseVolume=d"
    }
```

**Child record insert**

```
Update Parent add Child = [
    {  
       "@type":"d",
       "@class":"Child",
       "MarketName":"USD-CNY",
       "High":0.000083,
       "Low":0.00006815,
       "Volume":18688741.88795826,
       "Last":0.00006857,
       "Bid":0.00006857,
       "Ask":0.00006889,
       "BaseVolume":1412.08213181,
       "TimeStamp":"2017-07-19T17:12:59.44"
    }
] where MarketName = "USD-CNY"
```

---

**Poor performance on following query**

```
    select 
        MarketName, 
        Last, 
        Bid, 
        Ask, 
        High, 
        Low, 
        BaseVolume, 
        TimeStamp, 
        TimeStamp.asDateTime().format('yyyy-MM-dd') as date, 
        TimeStamp.asDateTime().format('hh:mm:ss') as time, 
        if(eval('TimeStamp.asDateTime().format("hh") between 0 and 11'),'PM','AM') as hour12 
    from Child where MarketName = "USD-CNY" order by TimeStamp desc
```

Additional information.

In the Child class, we have roughly 9 million records `WHERE MarketName = "USD-CNY"`

The execution of this query, takes roughly 33 - 40 seconds.

I have not done any indexing on the parent or child class, need some guidance on proper indexing techniques for a multimodel database.

Also, I am not expecting a response of the 9 million records. I am okay with paginating my results and just getting the top 100.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any other DBMS, OrientDB requires an index on the property you're using as a filter. Try executing this:

```
CREATE INDEX Child.MarketName ON Chile( market name ) UNIQUE
```

And you will see your query should be <300ms now.

For more information look at https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Create-Index.html.

Comment: Hi Lvca,  I understand that point. However, unlike any other DBMS, OrientDB has multiple index types. I am confused on what is the proper Index to use in what type of scenario. Furthermore, the index you advised is not possible on the child record because MarketName is not unique... we can have 1 Parent record with MarketName being Unique as 'ABC' but at the child level, we can have millions of `ABC` records. that's where the issue is coming in.

Comment: For this reason instead of UNIQUE, you can use the NON_UNIQUE index. If you don't do range queries, like `where name between 'a' and 'b'`, I suggest to use the HASH INDEX. Also, if Child is connected to the parent, and in a graph database you can traverse this relationship, why don't keep the name on the parent as unique index and then traverse all the `out('children')` to get them?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:
CREATE INDEX Child_Market_Time_idx ON Child (Marketname, TimeStamp) UNIQUE;

Comment: Did it help? What about storing child as standalone vertex and connect to parent through edges?

Comment: it helped some when my dataset is under 5 million records. However, with this particular project, I am facing a lot more data challenges than I normally would.  I am about to post another one right now.